# JMS - ActiveMQ - Servlet(Remote Server (Apache-ActiveMQ)) and Console Java Program

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, jms, activemq-classic

I have to send a message from a JAVA console program to a servlet on APACHE Tomcat 7.0.42 Server and using ActiveMQ 5.8.0 and send the acknowledgement message back to the program and continue the same thing until server goes offline.

I am completely new to JMS, i only know servlets,jsp,listeners,i.e. no frameworks.
I have: Eclipse-Kepler and JDK1.7 and was not able to configure ActiveMQ on Apache.
I read quite many blogs but nothing seems to work

Please, guide me how to go about the problem.

Thanks you.

Comment: "until online" or "until offline"? Your question is too broad: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Thank you Beyllium, i mean that until my server goes offline.
until now i have made 2 programs(both on console) 1 to send message to queue and other to read from it. I want something like listner that if it is active on the server side then it sends reply to every message that comes in...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a servlet-container only (Tomcat), you can create an unmanaged thread like this:

```
@WebListener
public class MyServletContextListener implements ServletContextListener {
    public void contextInitialized(final ServletContextEvent sce) {
        final java.util.Timer timer = new Timer();
        // Executes repeatedly (delay = 4000, period = 5000)
        timer.schedule(new ReplyTask(), 4000, 5000);
        sce.getServletContext().setAttribute("replyTaskTimer", timer);
    }

    public void contextDestroyed(final ServletContextEvent sce) {
        final java.util.Timer timer =
          (Timer) sce.getServletContext().getAttribute("replyTaskTimer");
        timer.cancel();
    }
}
```

In the `ReplyTask` just read the incoming queue, and send something on an outgoing queue (I suggest using two different queues to ping and pong). You **must cancel** the timer, that thread will otherwise survive undeployments and redeployments.

Note: If you were using an application server (JBoss for example), you could do that using a *Message driven bean (MDB)*. More elegant and concise, and the threading is managed by the application server. The extra benefit of using an application server like JBoss is the  integrated HornetQ JMS provider.

Comment: Thank you Beryllium...will try it out and will repost if face any problem!
i have a constraint that i can use tomcat only this is why...